# No sound after Lubuntu installation.

Tags: sound, ati

My hardware is pretty new; I've installed Lubuntu 11.10 and there's no sound nor volume icon in tray. The sound works well in Ubuntu. What can I do about it? I have two sound cards in this laptop, and one of them is HDMI, maybe the problem is because of that? Please help me?! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Lubuntu unlike Ubuntu does not make use of Pulseaudio.  Instead it uses Alsa for sound.

Thus, it is likely you need to look at `alsamixer` or its gui `alsamixgui` to control which sound elements are enable or disabled.

You may also need to look at using `alsamixer` as a startup application with the syntax similar to

`amixer -c 1 sset "PCM Capture Source" "Line"` - obviously you need to change the values to your sound source and output type.

Also - look to see if you have two sound cards - if you have, sometimes swapping the cards works:

```
sudo su
cd /usr/share/alsa 
cp -p alsa.conf alsa.conf.dist 
sed -i 's/card 0/card 1/g' alsa.conf
```

I answered a LXDE [sound-preferences](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80384/where-are-the-lxde-sound-preferences/80549#80549) question a while back which you may find useful.

As indicated in that answer, you could also install `pulseaudio` and use `pavucontrol` to control your pulseaudio setup.

As to a LXDE friendly volume control, [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/68098/how-can-i-change-the-volume-icon-in-lubuntu-11-10/68328#68328) is an accepted method you can try.

Comment: $ sudo bash

cd /usr/share/alsa
cp -p alsa.conf alsa.conf.dist
sed -i 's/card 0/card 1/g' alsa.conf
That solved my sound and my volume tray problem.

But how can I get volume indicators on screen, when I turn the volume up/down? Thanks

Comment: see my final edit. hope this helps.

Comment: Replace "card 0" by "card 1" worked for me too. I'm using LUBUNTU 15.04. And before doing this replace, I had installed *gstreamer0.10-alsa*

Answer (score 2):

I finally got sound working on HDMI. It was very interesting find though.

I saw differences in Pavucontrol without a video playing and with a video playing..
All i had to do was open Pavucontrol with a video playing and then select output to HDMI card.

Hope this helps all..

Answer (score 1):

This is what I did to fix the issue:

> Lubuntu shares many components with XFCE. My suggestion would be to
> use the XFCE4-Mixer. This still gives you a lightweight solution
> compatible with the lxde ethos.
>
> #### to install
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get install xfce4-mixer gstreamer0.10-alsa
> ```
>
> This installs the following limited number of xfce packages:
>
> ```
> exo-utils libgarcon-1-0 libgarcon-common libwnck-common libwnck22 libxres1 xfce4-mixer xfce4-panel
> ```
>
> #### to run
>
> Type `xfce4-mixer` in a lxterminal. In Options, in the Auto-Mute Mode
> drop-down menu, select "Disabled."

***Credit:** This is a close but not exact derivative of [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/80549/22949) by [fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/users/14356/fossfreedom) and [anonranger](https://askubuntu.com/users/79639/anonranger).*

Answer (score 0):

This may help: http://forum.xbmc.org/showthread.php?tid=76544&pid=1069025#pid1069025

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.